# Javascript uncaught reference error, call is not defined onclick

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, addeventlistener, jsfiddle

This is a javascript code which saves a textarea onto a text file. This fiddle does the same.:
https://jsfiddle.net/pzvvhfv6/ 

 I needed to add this feature in my code, so modified it so that onclick of the button, the text area is saved and a new file is created. But, for some strange reason, it shows uncaught reference error onclick. Below is the code Im working on.
https://jsfiddle.net/vu7thh34/

```
function call(){
   var create = document.getElementById('create');
    var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
    var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
    link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
    link.style.display = 'block';
  }
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="textbox">Type something here</textarea>  <button id="create">Create file</button> <a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>
```

Is there any problem with the code?

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle does not recognize inline handlers that reference functions in the lower JavaScript section.

Inline handlers are bad practice anyway - they're essentially `eval` inside HTML markup. Attach the listener properly using Javascript instead, and JSFiddle won't have any problem with it:

```
document.querySelector('#create').onclick = call;
```

Another option is to put your code in a `<script>` tag *in the HTML instead of in the Javascript* section of JSFiddle, but that's not a good idea.